# Tikz - airfoil forces and angle indication

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I've generated a ClarkY airfoil with `\draw` function, but is small. So I decide to resize it, but it resize all and it's not what I want [image]

This is what I did:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{!}{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \input{images/profile/clarky}
   \fill[black] (0.25,0) circle (0.01);
   \draw[gray, ->] (0.25,0) -- (0.25,0.5) node (mary) [black,below] {$y$};
   \draw [line width=0.01mm, blue] (-0.3,0) -- (1,0);
   \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
```

I want something like this and I don't know how to generate it. [image]

Thanks for help.

---

File `clarky.tex`:

```
\draw (1.0000000,0.0005993) -- 
(0.9900000,0.0029690) -- 
(0.9800000,0.0053335) -- 
(0.9700000,0.0076868) -- 
(0.9600000,0.0100232) -- 
(0.9400000,0.0146239) -- 
(0.9200000,0.0191156) -- 
(0.9000000,0.0235025) -- 
(0.8800000,0.0277891) -- 
(0.8600000,0.0319740) -- 
(0.8400000,0.0360536) -- 
(0.8200000,0.0400245) -- 
(0.8000000,0.0438836) -- 
(0.7800000,0.0476281) -- 
(0.7600000,0.0512565) -- 
(0.7400000,0.0547675) -- 
(0.7200000,0.0581599) -- 
(0.7000000,0.0614329) -- 
(0.6800000,0.0645843) -- 
(0.6600000,0.0676046) -- 
(0.6400000,0.0704822) -- 
(0.6200000,0.0732055) -- 
(0.6000000,0.0757633) -- 
(0.5800000,0.0781451) -- 
(0.5600000,0.0803480) -- 
(0.5400000,0.0823712) -- 
(0.5200000,0.0842145) -- 
(0.5000000,0.0858772) -- 
(0.4800000,0.0873572) -- 
(0.4600000,0.0886427) -- 
(0.4400000,0.0897175) -- 
(0.4200000,0.0905657) -- 
(0.4000000,0.0911712) -- 
(0.3800000,0.0915212) -- 
(0.3600000,0.0916266) -- 
(0.3400000,0.0915079) -- 
(0.3200000,0.0911857) -- 
(0.3000000,0.0906804) -- 
(0.2800000,0.0900016) -- 
(0.2600000,0.0890840) -- 
(0.2400000,0.0878308) -- 
(0.2200000,0.0861433) -- 
(0.2000000,0.0839202) -- 
(0.1800000,0.0810687) -- 
(0.1600000,0.0775707) -- 
(0.1400000,0.0734360) -- 
(0.1200000,0.0686204) -- 
(0.1000000,0.0629981) -- 
(0.0800000,0.0564308) -- 
(0.0600000,0.0487571) -- 
(0.0500000,0.0442753) -- 
(0.0400000,0.0391283) -- 
(0.0300000,0.0330215) -- 
(0.0200000,0.0253735) -- 
(0.0120000,0.0178581) -- 
(0.0080000,0.0137350) -- 
(0.0040000,0.0089238) -- 
(0.0020000,0.0058025) -- 
(0.0010000,0.0037271) -- 
(0.0005000,0.0023390) -- 
(0.0000000,0.0000000) -- 
(0.0005000,-.0046700) -- 
(0.0010000,-.0059418) -- 
(0.0020000,-.0078113) -- 
(0.0040000,-.0105126) -- 
(0.0080000,-.0142862) -- 
(0.0120000,-.0169733) -- 
(0.0200000,-.0202723) -- 
(0.0300000,-.0226056) -- 
(0.0400000,-.0245211) -- 
(0.0500000,-.0260452) -- 
(0.0600000,-.0271277) -- 
(0.0800000,-.0284595) -- 
(0.1000000,-.0293786) -- 
(0.1200000,-.0299633) -- 
(0.1400000,-.0302404) -- 
(0.1600000,-.0302546) -- 
(0.1800000,-.0300490) -- 
(0.2000000,-.0296656) -- 
(0.2200000,-.0291445) -- 
(0.2400000,-.0285181) -- 
(0.2600000,-.0278164) -- 
(0.2800000,-.0270696) -- 
(0.3000000,-.0263079) -- 
(0.3200000,-.0255565) -- 
(0.3400000,-.0248176) -- 
(0.3600000,-.0240870) -- 
(0.3800000,-.0233606) -- 
(0.4000000,-.0226341) -- 
(0.4200000,-.0219042) -- 
(0.4400000,-.0211708) -- 
(0.4600000,-.0204353) -- 
(0.4800000,-.0196986) -- 
(0.5000000,-.0189619) -- 
(0.5200000,-.0182262) -- 
(0.5400000,-.0174914) -- 
(0.5600000,-.0167572) -- 
(0.5800000,-.0160232) -- 
(0.6000000,-.0152893) -- 
(0.6200000,-.0145551) -- 
(0.6400000,-.0138207) -- 
(0.6600000,-.0130862) -- 
(0.6800000,-.0123515) -- 
(0.7000000,-.0116169) -- 
(0.7200000,-.0108823) -- 
(0.7400000,-.0101478) -- 
(0.7600000,-.0094133) -- 
(0.7800000,-.0086788) -- 
(0.8000000,-.0079443) -- 
(0.8200000,-.0072098) -- 
(0.8400000,-.0064753) -- 
(0.8600000,-.0057408) -- 
(0.8800000,-.0050063) -- 
(0.9000000,-.0042718) -- 
(0.9200000,-.0035373) -- 
(0.9400000,-.0028028) -- 
(0.9600000,-.0020683) -- 
(0.9700000,-.0017011) -- 
(0.9800000,-.0013339) -- 
(0.9900000,-.0009666) -- 
(1.0000000,-.0005993);
```

Comment: What is the `clarky` file?

Comment: How do I import the file to here?

Comment: Just add it as normal code: I am pretty sure that is only a code file

Comment: It's too long for this post, so I leave the link https://github.com/jcrcx/dwm/blob/master/clarky.tex

Comment: It is not that long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
Here we go

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6,transform shape]
   \scope[rotate=-5]\input{clarky}\endscope
   \coordinate (z) at (y |- x);
   \draw[line width=0.02mm,blue] (z) -- (x);
   \draw[line width=0.02mm,dash pattern=on 0.2mm off 0.2mm] (x) -- (y);
   \pic[draw,line width=0.01mm,angle radius=0.9cm] {angle=y--x--z};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### `clarky.tex` (a little modification made)

```
\draw[line width=0.04mm] (1.0000000,0.0005993) -- 
(0.9900000,0.0029690) -- 
(0.9800000,0.0053335) -- 
(0.9700000,0.0076868) -- 
(0.9600000,0.0100232) -- 
(0.9400000,0.0146239) -- 
(0.9200000,0.0191156) -- 
(0.9000000,0.0235025) -- 
(0.8800000,0.0277891) -- 
(0.8600000,0.0319740) -- 
(0.8400000,0.0360536) -- 
(0.8200000,0.0400245) -- 
(0.8000000,0.0438836) -- 
(0.7800000,0.0476281) -- 
(0.7600000,0.0512565) -- 
(0.7400000,0.0547675) -- 
(0.7200000,0.0581599) -- 
(0.7000000,0.0614329) -- 
(0.6800000,0.0645843) -- 
(0.6600000,0.0676046) -- 
(0.6400000,0.0704822) -- 
(0.6200000,0.0732055) -- 
(0.6000000,0.0757633) -- 
(0.5800000,0.0781451) -- 
(0.5600000,0.0803480) -- 
(0.5400000,0.0823712) -- 
(0.5200000,0.0842145) -- 
(0.5000000,0.0858772) -- 
(0.4800000,0.0873572) -- 
(0.4600000,0.0886427) -- 
(0.4400000,0.0897175) -- 
(0.4200000,0.0905657) -- 
(0.4000000,0.0911712) -- 
(0.3800000,0.0915212) -- 
(0.3600000,0.0916266) -- 
(0.3400000,0.0915079) -- 
(0.3200000,0.0911857) -- 
(0.3000000,0.0906804) -- 
(0.2800000,0.0900016) -- 
(0.2600000,0.0890840) -- 
(0.2400000,0.0878308) -- 
(0.2200000,0.0861433) -- 
(0.2000000,0.0839202) -- 
(0.1800000,0.0810687) -- 
(0.1600000,0.0775707) -- 
(0.1400000,0.0734360) -- 
(0.1200000,0.0686204) -- 
(0.1000000,0.0629981) -- 
(0.0800000,0.0564308) -- 
(0.0600000,0.0487571) -- 
(0.0500000,0.0442753) -- 
(0.0400000,0.0391283) -- 
(0.0300000,0.0330215) -- 
(0.0200000,0.0253735) -- 
(0.0120000,0.0178581) -- 
(0.0080000,0.0137350) -- 
(0.0040000,0.0089238) -- 
(0.0020000,0.0058025) -- 
(0.0010000,0.0037271) -- 
(0.0005000,0.0023390) -- 
(0.0000000,0.0000000) coordinate (y) -- 
(0.0005000,-.0046700) -- 
(0.0010000,-.0059418) -- 
(0.0020000,-.0078113) -- 
(0.0040000,-.0105126) -- 
(0.0080000,-.0142862) -- 
(0.0120000,-.0169733) -- 
(0.0200000,-.0202723) -- 
(0.0300000,-.0226056) -- 
(0.0400000,-.0245211) -- 
(0.0500000,-.0260452) -- 
(0.0600000,-.0271277) -- 
(0.0800000,-.0284595) -- 
(0.1000000,-.0293786) -- 
(0.1200000,-.0299633) -- 
(0.1400000,-.0302404) -- 
(0.1600000,-.0302546) -- 
(0.1800000,-.0300490) -- 
(0.2000000,-.0296656) -- 
(0.2200000,-.0291445) -- 
(0.2400000,-.0285181) -- 
(0.2600000,-.0278164) -- 
(0.2800000,-.0270696) -- 
(0.3000000,-.0263079) -- 
(0.3200000,-.0255565) -- 
(0.3400000,-.0248176) -- 
(0.3600000,-.0240870) -- 
(0.3800000,-.0233606) -- 
(0.4000000,-.0226341) -- 
(0.4200000,-.0219042) -- 
(0.4400000,-.0211708) -- 
(0.4600000,-.0204353) -- 
(0.4800000,-.0196986) -- 
(0.5000000,-.0189619) -- 
(0.5200000,-.0182262) -- 
(0.5400000,-.0174914) -- 
(0.5600000,-.0167572) -- 
(0.5800000,-.0160232) -- 
(0.6000000,-.0152893) -- 
(0.6200000,-.0145551) -- 
(0.6400000,-.0138207) -- 
(0.6600000,-.0130862) -- 
(0.6800000,-.0123515) -- 
(0.7000000,-.0116169) -- 
(0.7200000,-.0108823) -- 
(0.7400000,-.0101478) -- 
(0.7600000,-.0094133) -- 
(0.7800000,-.0086788) -- 
(0.8000000,-.0079443) -- 
(0.8200000,-.0072098) -- 
(0.8400000,-.0064753) -- 
(0.8600000,-.0057408) -- 
(0.8800000,-.0050063) -- 
(0.9000000,-.0042718) -- 
(0.9200000,-.0035373) -- 
(0.9400000,-.0028028) -- 
(0.9600000,-.0020683) -- 
(0.9700000,-.0017011) -- 
(0.9800000,-.0013339) -- 
(0.9900000,-.0009666) -- 
(1.0000000,-.0005993) coordinate (x);
```

#### Result

[image]

---

Scale it to an even higher factor if you want.